# table adapter update method doesn't update data grid

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, datagrid, tableadapter

I'm creating an application that needs to get a field's value, add something, then update that field. This compiles and runs just fine. However, this doesn't actually update the field when I check it inside the application (in a datagrid) as well as the actual database.

Here is where I update the row.

```
//This used to be: foreach (DataRow row in momDataSet.Clients.Rows)
//However, this doesn't seem to have any rows
foreach (DataRow row in clientsTableAdapter.GetData().Rows)
        {

            //all of these used to be row.ItemArray[]  
            if (row[6].Equals(clientID))
            {

                double oldAmt = Convert.ToDouble(row[8].ToString());
                double newAmt = oldAmt + amt;
                row[8] = newAmt;

                try
                {
                    // Tried momDataSet.AcceptChanges() here
                    this.clientsTableAdapter.Update(row);

                    //I tried momDataSet.AcceptChanges() after the update too
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message.ToString(), "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }

            }
        }
```

And here is the data grid I'm looking at inside the application. I open a form to run the above code then open another form to check it.

```
public partial class frmSearch : Form
{
    public frmSearch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.clientsTableAdapter.Fill(momDataSet.Clients);
    }
```

And this is the Update command text

```
UPDATE `Clients` SET `Last Name` = ?, `First Name` = ?, `E-mail Address` = ?, `Phone Number` = ?, `Rate` = ?, `Billing Type` = ?, `Outstanding balance` = ?, `Last Billed` = ?, `Notes` = ? WHERE (((? = 1 AND `Last Name` IS NULL) OR (`Last Name` = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND `First Name` IS NULL) OR (`First Name` = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND `E-mail Address` IS NULL) OR (`E-mail Address` = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND `Phone Number` IS NULL) OR (`Phone Number` = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND `Rate` IS NULL) OR (`Rate` = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND `Billing Type` IS NULL) OR (`Billing Type` = ?)) AND (`ClientID` = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND `Outstanding balance` IS NULL) OR (`Outstanding balance` = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND `Last Billed` IS NULL) OR (`Last Billed` = ?)))
```

I do not have a local copy of the database - insert works just fine. 
There IS an update method (it autocompletes in VS). 
I have a PK for every table.

The option to refresh the table (in edit data set -> right click table (in my case, Clients) -> configure -> advanced options) is not enabled. I'm using an OLEDB connection and I guess they aren't compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dragged a clients binding source onto the form and it's fixed!